# Avoid unexpected characters in powershell stream-to-file output

Tags: powershell

I would expect the following powershell command:

```
echo 'abc' > /test.txt
```

to fill the file `/test.txt` with exactly 3 bytes: `0x61, 0x62, 0x63`.

If I inspect the file, I see that its bytes are (all values are hex):

```
ff fe 61 00 62 00 63 00 0d 00 0a 00
```

Regardless of what output I try to stream into a file, the following steps apply in the given order, transforming the resulting file contents:

1. Append `\r\n` (`0d 0a`) to the end of the output
2. Insert a null byte (`00`) after every character of the output
3. Prepend `ff fe` to the entire output

Transformation #1 is relatively tolerable, but the other two transformations are a real pain.

How can I stream content more precisely (without these transformations) using powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
'abc' | out-file -filepath .\test.txt -encoding ascii -nonewline
```

should get you 3 bytes instead of 12

```
61 62 63
```

Comment: A bit more verbose, but works like a charm - also just noting to other users that `-nonewline` will remove any newlines from the actual content!

Comment: 'abc' | set-content -path .\test.txt -nonewline also should work

Comment: @Gershy, to add some info: `ff fe` at the start are the two bytes making up the UTF-16 LE _BOM_, because in _Windows PowerShell_ `>`, due to being an effective alias of `Out-File`, creates UTF-16LE ("Unicode") files by default (PowerShell (Core) 7+ now fortunately uses BOM-less UTF-8 by default). In UTF-16LE, ASCII-range characters have `00` (NUL) values as the 2nd byte of each 2-byte code unit encoding a single (BMP) character. Yes, it is unfortunate that `-NoNewLine` removes _all_ newlines - [GitHub issue #5108](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5108) asks for `-NoLastNewLine`.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, that's helpful!